# Forcing Variable value from outside of the script if argument is passed

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing, argparse

I was thinking what's the best way to force a variable value from outside the script.

Now i'm using configuration file, but i was asked to provide a way to force parameters from outside.

---

**Actual code**

```
source "$1.iconf"

// some code that uses variables declared and initialized in the configuration file
```

This is the standard case that use the variables valorized in a static way in that configuration file. I just run the script passing the configuration file name.

```
./myscript.sh configuration_file
```

Now in the config file some variables are defined:

```
Var1 = some value
Var2 = 42
Var3 = "foo"
```

---

**what i should be able to do:**

```
./myscript.sh configuration_file --Var1="Value defined from outside"
```

---

```
source "$1.iconf"

//Check if some variables are passed from run string
if [ <Passed_From_Run_String_condition> ]; then
    //override variables value
    //maybe some kind of arguments parsing??
fi

//some code that uses variables declared and initialized in the configuration file (and maybe overridden by passed values)
```

Comment: So you would like to first override variables in your script based on variables passed in as parameters (2nd order of precedence) and then you would like to override variables by values present in the configuration file (1st order of precedence)?

Comment: First assign value from config file, then if some variable are differently passed via params, then override that specific variables value

Comment: Added a new answer, it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script will first source variables stored in a configuration file passed as the first parameter to the script, then it will take as a second parameter variables that can be used to overwrite values from the configuration file or create new variables if they didn't previously exist.

foo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source "$1"
eval "typeset $2"

echo ${var1}
```

config

```
var1="foo"
```

run script:

```
./foo.sh config var1=yup
```

output:

```
yup
```

The value "foo" in the config file was replaced by the value passed in via the second parameter "yup".  If you would like to make a variable read only, so the value can not be changed, you can use typeset -r to define a variable.

Comment: ok it works fine, thank you! :) But this way someone could be able to write some command that mustn't be executed (rm for example), do you know if there is a way to prevent this?

Comment: Sure, you can do something like eval "typeset $2" which will ensure that you are declaring a variable and not executing some kind of other command.

Comment: Great! Seems to work :D I can do the same using export instead? What's the difference?

Comment: I did some testing and there are at least two ways of execute commands: 1) `./foo.sh config var1='rm *'`  ----- 2) `./foo.sh config var1=$(rm *)`

Comment: this kind of commands are executed already outside of the script in the sub-shell, so i can't avoid them `./foo.sh config var1=$(rm *)`

Comment: Yea well if a user has privileges to rm files that they can certainly do that, doesn't have to do with the script.